# Chrome wont load any page (sometimes loadw them after a delay)

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome

My Chrome (`Version 37.0.2062.94 m`) does not load any page. Sometimes pages are loaded after 10 secs delay. I did not install any new extensions or programs.

- Tried incognito mode
- Tried disabling network prediction services
- tried other browsers

The best demo of this problem can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2laI-8sktA)

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit build?

Comment: @Sathya nope that was the stable 32bits version, but even with the 64bits I get the same issue..